# Java code run from a Windows CLI still gets a null System.console()

Tags: java, windows, command-line

There are a bunch of questions here and around the 'net about working with Java's System.console() in various environments.  Most of them have to do with the restrictions and caveats of getting a null return, i.e., "when no console is available".  Fair enough.

My confusion stems from seeing a null return even when I'm working from a command-line environment on Windows.  (Note, this is **NOT** about doing anything from inside Eclipse; that's been asked and answered a million times already, and I'm not even using Eclipse.  Also not talking about double-clicking or right-clicking or any other kind of clicking on JAR files; there's obviously no console when you're starting from a GUI file manager.)

So far I've tried the following combinations, all under Windows 7:

- default Windows\System32 "java"
- default Windows\System32 "javaw"
- Sun/Oracle's standard JavaSE JRE 7u25 "java"
- Sun/Oracle's standard JavaSE JRE 7u25 "javaw"
- Sun/Oracle's JavaSE JDK 7u25 "java"
- Sun/Oracle's JavaSE JDK 7u25 "javaw"

also

- all 6 of the above under both Cygwin's mintty, and plain old CMD.EXE

I thought the whole point of the java/javaw distinction was that one had a console and the other didn't, but even though I'm running all 12 attempts from a command-line prompt, System.console() is always null.

The testbed code is simple enough, and does the expected thing under other OSes (e.g., Linux, where System.console() is always there from an xterm and whatnot, but becomes null when stdin is redirected from /dev/null).

What virgin goat do we have to sacrifice to the dark gods of Java to get a System.console() in Windows when the user is running from a CLI?

Comment: You're in the Windows command box (Windowskey + r, "cmd", ENTER), and your Java console application returns null for System.console()? Impossibru! If that's your problem: Check if your Java system settings are weird. Mine look like this: https://i.imgur.com/0oSrRWY.png ........ Also, even though this is NOT about double-clicking, you saying "there's obviously no console when you're starting from a GUI file manager" makes me think that you'd *like* if that would work, so here's a solution I built a few hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32547250/3500521

Comment: Please show us your code and tell how're you running the program. Otherwise the question won't be solved. It *should* work directly in Windows console.

Comment: @ForNeVeR Well, this was 3 years ago... the "code" was "if (System.console() == null) print_a_complaint();" because that's how the Console class is obtained and that's all there is to it.  If it's supported, it's a singleton and that function returns it, otherwise it returns null.  There is no other code because nothing else inside Java can effect console support.

Comment: @ForNeVeR As for how it was being called, that also doesn't matter in this case, other than the fact that we were using java.exe and NOT javaw.exe, i.e., there should have been a console.  The actual problem for everything other than CMD.EXE is that Java's JNI support for "is this a terminal, yes/no?" is extremely limited and can't handle pseudoterminals.  The best examination to date is under mintty:  https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/56   The problem with CMD.EXE was apparently related to user permissions.

Comment: I'd close the question as pointless now, but I apparently don't have the necessary privs to do that.

Comment: @TiStrga for completeness, I believe that [winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) is the best option today to work around a Windows terminal quirks if you really need to.